# Помогите пожалуйста что здесь не так (JavaScript, jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Правильно ли написана функция.

Здесь должно быть тип если есть (верстак-1, дерево-2, палка-1) то выполняется функция если тоже самое только больше то выполняется функция если меньше то ничего.

Функция работает но не проверяться условия.

```
    $('#block_sword').click(function(){
        if(workbench=="1", wood=="2", stick=="1"){
          wood--;
          wood--;
          stick--;
          sword++;
          $('#wood_text').text(wood);
          $('#stick_text').text(stick);
          $('#sword_text').text(sword);
        }else if(workbench > "1", wood > "2", stick > "1"){
          wood--;
          wood--;
          stick--;
          sword++;
          $('#wood_text').text(wood);
          $('#stick_text').text(stick);
          $('#sword_text').text(sword);
        }else if(workbench < "1", wood < "2", stick < "1"){
          
        }
      });
```

Comment: Что это за запятые в условиях? Что за сравнения? Разбейте условия на мельчайшие части, смотрите их, смотрите тип, и сами условия тоже, тем же console.log().. Может хоть какая мысль появится, а то смотреть больно

Comment: @InDevX: причём не только смотреть, но и буквально боль физическая - силу facepalm не рассчитал :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выглядит всё это ооочень странно в целом........но если не вдаваться в суть что этот код делает, а только в условия, то можно так

```
$('#block_sword').click(function(){
    if (workbench < "1" && wood < "2" && stick < "1") //??? workbench < "1" || wood < "2" || stick < "1"   
        return;
    
    if (workbench >= "1" && wood >= "2" && stick >= "1") { //??? workbench >= "1" || wood >= "2" || stick >= "1"
        wood--;
        wood--;
        stick--;
        sword++;
        $('#wood_text').text(wood);
        $('#stick_text').text(stick);
        $('#sword_text').text(sword);
    }
});
```

Comment: Создает меч из дерева и палок x) У автора еще потенциальная ошибка с типами, `"111" < "2" // true`. Если хотя бы тут вместо `"1", "2"` записать числа, даже если прилетит строка в переменных - при сравнении она бдет преобразоваться в число и правильно работать. И... `wood -= 2;`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME про типы я тоже вначале подумал....но потом посмотрел на `wood--;
        wood--;
        stick--;
        sword++;` и подумал что уж там то наверное в таком случае будет int))

Comment: `let x = "10"; console.log(--x); // 9` они умеют и со строкой)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME ну, буде надеяться.....))